# R merge many csv's using ID column?

Tags: r

I have bunch of csv's that that all share the same ID column and an additional column. I need to combine them all together into one csv in R based on the ID column. An example of my csv's below, but I have around 5,000 csv in need to combine into a single dataset:

Table 1

| ID | Red |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 7 |

Table 2

| ID | Blue |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 2 |

Table 3

| ID | Green |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 |
| 2 | 8 |

Output table

| ID | Red | Blue | Green |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 6 | 9 |
| 2 | 7 | 2 | 8 |

I know I need to list all the files but haven't been able to find what function to use. I can combine two CSVs using the merge function, would I need to loop it or is there a single function that can do many?

```
setwd("C:/Desktop/CSVs")
all_files <- list.files(pattern = ".csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably `Reduce`:

> ‘Reduce’ uses a binary function to successively combine the
> elements of a given vector and a possibly given initial value.

```r
L <- list(
   data.frame(ID = 1:2, Red = c(5,7)),
   data.frame(ID = 1:2, Blue = c(6,2)),
   data.frame(ID = 1:2, Green = c(9,8)))
Reduce(\(x,y) merge(x, y, by = "ID"), L)
```

You can get a list of the file contents (`L`) via `lapply(all.files, read.csv)`.

Just plain `Reduce(merge, L)` works just as well but it's safer to write an anonymous function as in the example, to make sure you're merging on the specified column/key. (Unfortunately you can't say `Reduce(merge, L, by = "ID")`, i.e. `Reduce()` doesn't have a `...` argument that could pass additional argument through to `merge()`.)

Comment: Surely this has been asked and answered before.

Comment: probably, but I couldn't find it quickly ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list ;